# Joystick with Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb, remote-desktop, joystick

Why can't I use my Logitech Extreme 3D pro joystick work through remote desktop, as does a USB mouse or keyboard?  Joystick is connected to Laptop A (can be running either Windows XP or Windows 7). I am remoting into Laptop B.  I need the Joystick to work on Laptop B through remote desktop. 
Any solutions?

Comment: Hi,
many years, but did you find a solution?
Thx!

Answer (score 3):

When you connect to the Remote Desktop, click on **Show Options**, choose **Local Resources**, More, and make sure that the USB Joystick pops up under "*Other supported Plug and Play (PnP) devices*".

[image]

Comment: too bad, logitech joysticks don't appear in that list. x-box controllers do.

Comment: Do your Logitech joysticks appear in Device Manager? How are they connected? Are drivers installed on both your source and target machine?

Comment: Thx! yes, detected and available also via "joysticks" of windows, but doesn't appear under this list. I found "usb network gate" SW to redirect these upon windows RDP